# Content control not accessbile from content page?

Tags: asp.net, controls, content-pages

My content page looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Basket.aspx.cs" Inherits="Basket" Title="Untitled Page" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

Now, I would like to add some controls dynamically to the content when page loads, so I am trying the following code:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     Content2. // I want to add controls to it dynamically
  }
```

The problem is that the `Content2` control is not visible by the compiler and I am getting error about missing directive or assembly reference.

Any solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you can't get a reference to that `asp:Content` control is because it does not stay around when the page is combined with the masterpage. Basically ASP takes all the controls from inside these `asp:Content` sections and makes them children of the `ContentPlaceholder` controls inside the masterpage.

As [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.content.aspx) says: **A Content control is not added to the control hierarchy at runtime. Instead, the contents within the Content control are directly merged into the corresponding ContentPlaceHolder control.**

That means that if you want to add more controls to that section, you will have to get a reference to the `ContentPlaceholder` control in the masterpage and add them to it. Something like:

```
ContentPlaceHolder myContent = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
myContent.Controls.Add(??);
```

Notice you are using the `ContentPlaceHolderID` value, NOT the `ID` of the `asp:Content` section.

Comment: Thanks, I mark it as an answer. I can understand that it dissapears at runtime, but why I cant access it in designtime like other controls. If I see that control in WYSIWYG editor, than I should be able to acces that control in C# file also. From my point of view it is a bug in design commited by Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

I will recommend that you put a placeholder control in content and use it to add controls. For example,

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Basket.aspx.cs" Inherits="Basket" Title="Untitled Page" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
  <asp:Placeholder runat="server" ID="Content1Controls" />
</asp:Content>

..
```

And

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     Content1Controls.Controls.Add(...
  }
```

Comment: +1 For the nice idea how to overcome the problem, thanks:) But why the content control itself is not accessible, this really intrigue me.

Comment: @Wodzu, thats because Content control does not get added to page. See more detailed response by patmortech.